# The best way to pre-populate remote data in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app, I need to retrieve multiple collections of static data from remote REST endpoints. Those data collections will be used throughout the entire application life cycle as static lookup lists. I would like for all those lists to be populated upon the initial application startup, and to be retained and made available to multiple controllers. I would prefer not to load any additional data dynamically, as one of the assumptions for this particular app, is that, once loaded, any further network connections may not be available for a while.
It is OK to take an initial hit, as the users will be preoccupied by reading a static content of the first page anyway.
I was thinking of making this mass loading a part of the initial application run block, and stick all this static data into various collections attached to the $rootScope (which would make that available everywhere else)
What is the best way to handle this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I approach this is to use a service (or a collection of services I nest), and set caching to `true` in the `$http` get functions. This way the service can be passed into any controller you desire, having cached results available to you without the need for additional http requests.

I can try to put this into an example if this is unclear to you, let me know.

edit: you can either wait for the first call to this service to do this caching, or do this on app load, either way is possible.

Comment: makes sense. use services, make them cache the results, and call all these services first from within a controller attached to the first view. thanks!

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg - You can avoid making the extra trips back to the database altogether by extending the script directive.

Comment: @Josh - Could you give a bit more details on how to do that (this is my second Angular app)?

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg - If you look at the link to the blog post in my answer it will give you full details, as well as a link to an entire Plunkr that shows the whole thing working live.

Comment: @Josh while that is actually pretty interesting, I'm not sure how embedding JSON into the app will help fetching data out of a rest service. Maybe I'm missing something but isn't this another way of hard coding a list into a service?

Comment: @Jorg - Not at all. The idea is that if you already know your application will need the data, then you can pre-package it on the server and send it down with your initial page load, or a template. You don't have to hard code anything, just render the DB/service call directly into a `<script>` tag as JSON. The benefit is that if you have several of these calls you **know** you are going to make anyway, then it's better to send it down all at once rather than having to make another round trip to the server.

Comment: Pretty cool idea. Being so new to Angular, I do not have a strong feel as to which one will bester suite my case, but I will give both a try and see .

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly enough, I **just wrote a [blog post about extending the script directive](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/25/how-to-extend-angular-script-directive.html) to handle this very scenario**.

The concept is simple. You embed JSON data in your page when it loads from the server like so:

```
<script type="text/context-info">
{
   "name":"foo-view",
   "id":34,
   "tags":[
      "angular",
      "javascript",
      "directives"
   ]
}
</script>
```

Then you extend the script directive so it parses the data out for you and makes it available to other parts of your application via a service.

```
if(attr.type === 'text/context-info'){
  var contextInfo = JSON.parse(element[0].text);

  //Custom service that can be injected into
  // the decorator
  contextInfoService.addContextInfo(contextInfo);
}
```

You can see a live demo of it here: http://embed.plnkr.co/mSFgaO/preview