# MEAN Stack: static list best practice

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

This is a general best practice question:

I am building a MEAN  (mongo, express, angular, node) website. I have a user object that can have a gender [Mr or Miss] and a city [Paris, New York, Anything]

So this is quite a common problem: where should I store those lists that rarely change and never exceed, let's say, 50 rows.

1/ Is it better to have them stored in the database (mongo) with a foreign key in the user table. And so I have a gender table and a city table. But everytime I access these lists I need to read the base?

2/ Is it better to have them store in a file or in a controller? But this is a bit dangerous I think.

3/ Maybe there is another way that I don't know about.

I am not sure what is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you concerned about an extra database call to get a list out?

If it was me I'd pick option 1 and I'd be storing it in a database. If you store value descriptions only front-end you'll run the risk of discrepancies if you end up updating your database's foreign keys but forget to update your controller or file and it seems rather untrustworthy. It also makes it more difficult to provide internationalization, because you'll have to start storing names and genders in files or controllers in multiple languages. Storing things is what a database is for and an additional call to get a list out is really not that big an impact on your performance.

Angular's `$http` object, which you are probably using to call your API has a caching option, which means you'll only need to retrieve the list once per app instantiation.

You could alternatively have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22826252/502613) by Josh who found a way to pre populate a directive with JSON from the server before loading it.

Comment: No I am not concerned with extra call. I was just wondering if that the best way to do it before I do it :). Thanks for the link, this is exactly what I need! I will go for this solution.